# how to sort application properties value

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, sorting

Is it possible to sort a `List` interface with object of `ArrayList()`?

`List</*classname*/> list = new ArrayList<>();`

I'm using `application.properties` of Spring boot to set the value in List interface

ModuleNames.java

```
public class ModuleNames {

    private String moduleId;
    private String moduleName;

    //getters & setters.
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getModuleNames", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
public @ResponseBody List<String> getModuleNames() {

        List<ModuleNames> moduleNamesList = new ArrayList<>();
        moduleNamesList.add(new ModuleNames("Country", env.getProperty("bulkUpload.location.country")));
        moduleNamesList.add(new ModuleNames("State", env.getProperty("bulkUpload.location.state")));
        moduleNamesList.add(new ModuleNames("City", env.getProperty("bulkUpload.location.city")));
        moduleNamesList.add(new ModuleNames("Area Pincode", env.getProperty("bulkUpload.location.areaPincode")));

        return moduleNamesList;
```

does anybody know how to sort the list.

I've tried

1. `moduleNamesList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());`
2. `Collections.sort(moduleNamesList);`

but both doesn't seem to work. Please help me here

Comment: Do you want to sort moduleNamesList?

Comment: on what basis.... moduleId or moduleName ?

Comment: @Nitika on moduleName

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid defining the comparison logic by using an instance method reference and the Comparator.comparing method – which extracts and creates a Comparable based on that function.

We're going to use the getters to build the Lambda expression.

**sort the list by moduleName:**

```java
moduleNamesList.sort(Comparator.comparing(ModuleNames::getModuleName));
```

**sort the list by moduleName in reverse order:**

```java
moduleNamesList.sort(Comparator.comparing(ModuleNames::getModuleName).reversed());
```

**sort the list by first moduleName and then moduleId:**

```java
moduleNamesList.sort(Comparator.comparing(ModuleNames::getModuleName).thenComparing(ModuleNames::getModuleId));
```

You can also use custom comparator:[Use This Reference](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-lambda-comparator-example/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to write your custom comparator for ModuleNames object, because Java doesn't know how to sort it as it is not a primitive type.

For example:

```
Collections.sort(moduleNamesList, new Comparator<ModuleNames>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ModuleNames o1, ModuleNames o2) {
            return o1.getModuleId().compareTo(o2.getModuleId());
        }
    });
```

or

```
moduleNamesList.sort(new Comparator<ModuleNames>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ModuleNames o1, ModuleNames o2) {
            return o1.getModuleName().compareTo(o2.getModuleName());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
moduleNamesList.sort(Comparator.comparing(ModuleNames::getName));
moduleNamesList.sort(Comparator.comparing(mn -> mn.name));
```

Or even more sorted:

```
moduleNamesList.sort(Comparator.comparing(ModuleNames::getName)
                     .thenComparing(ModuleNames::getId));
```